# Como realizar uma coleta de informações de um arquivo JSON via AJAX (sem uso de Jquery)

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, eu já venho programando a alguns anos e estou bem acomodado com o uso do `Jquery`, e é bem comum realizar chamadas `AJAX` onde é recebido como resposta um arquivo `JSON`, porem eu quase nunca fiz ele de maneira "pura", em outras palavras, sem Jquery, e queria entender de uma forma um pouco mais explicada de como realizar esse request.

A pergunta é: Como eu coleto a `data` que o arquivo vai retornar?

Atualmente meu código está escrito desta forma:

```
//On load eveneto
window.onload = async function(){

    //Chamando o Ajax
    let value = await requestJson();

    console.log(value);

}

async function requestJson(){

    //Retornando uma promessa
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //[+] AJAX_________
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            resolve(this.responseText);

        }

        xhttp.open("GET", "file.json", true);
        xhttp.send();
        //[-] AJAX_________



    });

}
```

Comment: **NOTA :** Stack Overflow Brasil ta com bot de negativação, eu não fiz a pergunta a dois minutos, e fui negativado em minha pergunta. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está praticamente pronto, faltou apenas verificar o status da requisição dentro do `onreadystatechange`, utilizando a propriedade `readyState`, ela pode ter os seguintes valores:

> - 0  | **UNSENT**    open() não foi chamado ainda.
> - 1  | **OPENED**    send() não foi    chamado ainda.
> - 2  | **HEADERS_RECEIVED**  send() foi chamado, e cabeçalhos e    status estão disponíveis.
> - 3  | **LOADING**   Download; responseText contém    dados parciais.
> - 4  | **DONE**  A operação está concluída.

Também é possível verificar o código de retorno da requisição, utilizando a propriedade `status`, aí é o status HTTP padrão, você pode ver mais [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

```js
//On load eveneto
window.onload = async function(){

    //Chamando o Ajax
    let value = await requestJson();

    console.log(value);

}

async function requestJson(){

    //Retornando uma promessa
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //[+] AJAX_________
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onload = function() {
          if(this.readyState == 4) {
              console.log("Código de retorno HTTP:", this.status);
              resolve(this.responseText);
          }    
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", "https://httpbin.org/get", true);
        xhttp.send();
        //[-] AJAX_________
    });

}
```

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Usando_XMLHttpRequest
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHTTPRequest