# Django Filter ignorando caracteres/símbolos

Tags: regex, django, orm

**Problema**

Usuários que cadastram com o email no gmail podem criar várias contas apenas mudando o . (ponto) de lugar. Por exemplo: stack.overflow@gmail.com e stackover.flow@gmail.com direcionam para o mesmo email porem são duas contas no meu site. Então o usuário pode fazer um spam de contas considerando isso.

**Dúvida**

Gostaria de saber se posso fazer um filter ignorando pontos. Dessa forma, caso tenha @gmail.com no email, eu busco pelo email ignorando ponto tanto na string de busca quando no filter do django. Algo nesse sentido:

```
User.objects.filter(email = useremail.replace('.').('')).exclude(email__ignore_char = '.')
```

Dessa forma eu estaria buscando **stackoverflow@gmail.com** em toda minha base e ignoraria o **.** nos registros que tenho também.

Comment: Qual seria o motivo para o downvote? Obrigado

Comment: Parece que alguém programou um bot para negativar todas as perguntas. Acabei de fazer uma pergunta e fui negativado instantaneamente, sem explicação. O mesmo ocorreu com outras pessoas. Veja outro caso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438365/como-realizar-uma-coleta-de-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-um-arquivo-json-via-ajax-sem-uso-de

Comment: Ah sim, realmente foi logo após criar a pergunta..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um colega meu encontrou um gist com uma solução que resolveu o problema:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value
if '@gmail.com' in email:
    email_gmail_spam = email.replace('.', '')
    user = User.objects.annotate(
        fixed_email=Func(
            F('email'),
            Value('.'), Value(''),
            function='replace',
        )
    ).filter(fixed_email=email_gmail_spam)

    if user.exists():
        message.error("Ja existe um usuário com este email cadastrado.")
```